# Can a standalone server be converted into a farm?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

We have a SharePoint 2016 Standalone server, can that be converted to a SharePoint FARM 2016 ?

Comment: What is your exact setup today? One Server with SharePoint and SQL-Server? Or one SharePoint-Server and a separate SQL-Server? What is your expected setup after "conversion"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change the role in Central Admin -> System Settings -> Convert.